# Is resonance same as constant phase difference in waves?

Tags: waves, resonance

Confused whether [resonance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance) means constant phase difference (mathematically).

Comment: This sounds closer to a description of coherence.

Answer (score 0):

I would answer this question considering mechanical systems since it is the system with respect to which the doubt has arose(in my opinion).when driving frequency is equal to natural frequency and phase diff is such that constructive interference occurs then resonance happens.